# AWK - print only duplicates

Tags: awk, getline

I have a file:

```
jeden
dwa
jeden
trzy
trzy
cztery
piec
jeden
```

This command prints out:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {while ((getline < "file") > 0) if(a[$0]++) print }'
jeden
trzy
jeden
```

I want to print all duplicate:

```
jeden
jeden
trzy
trzy
jeden
```

**EDIT:**

I found an example that works.

```
awk '{if (x[$1]) { x_count[$1]++; print $0; if (x_count[$1] == 1) { print x[$1] } } x[$1] = $0}' file
```

I want to do the same, but with getline.

Comment: Another: `sort file | uniq -D`

Comment: Why do you want to use getline?

Comment: @Kevin Because I will need it in the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN {while ((getline < "file") > 0) { a[$0]++; if(a[$0] == 2) print; if (a[$0] >= 2) print }}'
```

When the count is two, it prints the line. When the count is greater than or equal to two, it prints the line. So for the second occurrence, the line is printed twice to "catch up".

Comment: @Tedee12345: Note that this could affect the ordering slightly.

Comment: @ Dennis Williamson Can you give an example of this subject?

Comment: @Tedee12345: If you had a, b, b, a, for example, b would be printed before a. This might not be undesirable, however.

Comment: @ Dennis Williamson Now I understand. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to either store all lines in memory or take a second pass through the file. It's probably easier to do the first, and unless it's a massive file, you probably have the memory for it. You can stuff this onto one line, of course, but for ease of understanding here it is as a file.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{ 
        lines[NR] = $0
        counts[$0]++ 
}             

END { 
        for(i = 0; i < length(lines); i++) {
                if(counts[lines[i]] > 1) {
                        print lines[i]
                }       
        }       
}
```

---

Also, your original would be more concisely written as this:

```
$ awk 'a[$0]++' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(x in a)if(a[x]>1)for(i=1;i<=a[x];i++)print x}' file
```

Comment: It looks like he wants the lines in order.